# MySQL CPU usage difference between my local server and Linode server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, linode

I have 2 similar servers, one on my local computer, the other on Linode.
OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on both.

When I import a large database into MySQL, my local computer uses less than 10% of CPU while the Linode server uses 100% of CPU.
So Linode server completes the import much faster than my local computer.

What configuration makes the difference?

Comment: Which "import" mechanism are you using?  What versions of MySQL?  How big is the 'large' database?

Comment: And what are the CPUs?

Comment: @RickJames: I created a backup file using mysqldump and import it using mysql command. The large database is about 1GB.

Comment: I guess the problem was that the local computer uses an external HDD and the database backup file is on that. So reading the drive slows down. I need to verify my theory, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSDs are on the order of 10 times as fast as HDDs.  That does not *directly* explain "100% cpu".  Instead, if the CPU @10% too 10 times as long (*elapsed* time), then that matches a CPU @100%.

Comment: I confirm that the problem was slow drive. So I changed mysql data dir to SSD and now CPU is almost 100%. The HDD was the bottle neck.

Comment: @SamKong - Now we can look at the query to see if a better index or better formulation would decrease the CPU.  (I find that nearly all 100%-CPU queries can be sped up.)